# Drawing diagonal line within Silverlight Chart

Tags: silverlight, charts

I need to draw a diagonal line so we can demonstrate a middle line for the progress of something which may not necessarily to go (0,0), (1,1)....(4, 4), it may deviate according to the ratio between X and Y Axes.

After I agreed to draw the line as a `LineSeries`, I have this problem of duplicating axes.

**The Problem:** I need to draw 3 line series.
**1st:** Amount  -> The visits amount.
**2nd:** Target  -> The monthly target (this is a X-axis parallel line).
**3rd:** Midline -> The middle line of a normal progress of visits.

the Amount series could include days from day 1 to day 10, but the Midline series always have to demonstrate all month days (for March it is from 1 to 31). So, **we have 2 series** now (other than the target) **which share the same X axis**, and **since their data is different each one is creating its own X axis** (top and bottom), I want both series to take the same bottom X axis (from day 1 to day 31) and when the day 10 comes the Amount series line will stop being drawn but the Midline will continue till day 31.

Here is a Pic of what I want:
[image: Middle line series]

See the black line? this is what I want to be the middle line, but instead till now the gray line is what I was able to do.

**In this picture,** I only have 4 data points, if they were really 31 data points the mid line will be drawn correctly, but I want to draw it correctly regardless of the data points count. for simplicity purposes the duplicate upper X axis is not shown in this example because I gave the similar data to both series-es but if I assigned the whole month data to the middle line it will create an upper 1-31 days X axis.

Comment: Can you add detail to your PS?  A simple line series works fine for me.  What problems are you facing with axes?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Question updated.

Comment: So you want the line from (0,0) to (9,8) ? It can be achieved by using INotifyCollectionChanged and updating a line model in the ViewModel. And line is just a Line tag under Chart tag in XAML. Anyway, could you attach an image with an example to your question?

Comment: I'm now confused about your math.  "p1(0,0) to p2(maxX, maxY)" does not describe a line of "Slope = 1", so which is it?  I'd challange your point of view that another series is overkill, in fact any other approach is going to much more difficult.  Finally you need not permit automatic axes, you can be perscriptive over what Axis exist and how they are used.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, @vorrtex. Question is fully re-framed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got added evidence that a first idea is the most correct.
If you want just a black line - the solution is quite simple:

1. Change the control template of the chart
2. Add a dummy `LineSeries` to display Legend on the right of the chart.

Here is the chart:

```
   <charting:Chart Grid.Row="1">
        <charting:Chart.Series>
            <charting:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding LineItems}" IndependentValuePath="Date" DependentValuePath="Value" />
            <charting:LineSeries Title="Middle Line">
                <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    </Style>
                </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
            </charting:LineSeries>
        </charting:Chart.Series>
        <charting:Chart.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:Chart">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,15,0,15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <datavis:Legend x:Name="Legend" Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                            <chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
                                <Grid Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Style="{TemplateBinding PlotAreaStyle}" />
                                <Border Canvas.ZIndex="10" BorderBrush="#FF919191" BorderThickness="1" />
                                <local:LineControl Canvas.ZIndex="11"/>
                            </chartingprimitives:EdgePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </charting:Chart.Template>
    </charting:Chart>
```

It contains `LineControl` inside the control template, it is a `UserControl` with the following code:

**LineControl.xaml**

```
<Line x:Name="line" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
```

**LineControl.xaml.cs**

```
    public LineControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(LineControl_SizeChanged);
    }

    void LineControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.line.Y1 = this.ActualHeight;
        this.line.X2 = this.ActualWidth;
    }
```

Advantages of this solution:

- works with any types of axes
- automatically redraws itself if data items or axes are changed.

Another solution - using a behavior.
Chart XAML has few changes: I added the behavior and removed the `UserControl` and the Middle Line `LineSeries`

```
<chartingprimitives:EdgePanel x:Name="ChartArea" Style="{TemplateBinding ChartAreaStyle}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:DiagonalLineBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The behavior class:

```
public class DiagonalLineBehavior : Behavior<EdgePanel>
{
    private DateTimeAxis xAxis;
    private LinearAxis yAxis;

    public Brush LineColor { get; set; }

    public DiagonalLineBehavior()
    {
        if (this.LineColor == null)
            this.LineColor = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Loaded);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xAxis = this.AssociatedObject.Children.OfType<DateTimeAxis>().FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X);
        yAxis = this.AssociatedObject.Children.OfType<LinearAxis>().FirstOrDefault(ax => ax.Orientation == AxisOrientation.Y);
        if (xAxis == null || yAxis == null)
            return;

        this.UpdateLine();
    }

    private void UpdateLine()
    {
        //Collection with two items: start point and end point
        var lineSource = new[] { 
            new ChartPointModel(xAxis.ActualMinimum, yAxis.ActualMinimum), 
            new ChartPointModel(xAxis.ActualMaximum, yAxis.ActualMaximum) };

        //This code creates a line with many intermediate points
        //var pointCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(((TimeSpan)(xAxis.ActualMaximum - xAxis.ActualMinimum)).TotalDays/xAxis.ActualInterval);
        //var yInterval = (yAxis.ActualMaximum - yAxis.ActualMinimum).Value / (double)pointCount;
        //var lineSource = Enumerable.Range(0, pointCount)
        //                 .Select(i => new ChartPointModel(xAxis.ActualMinimum.Value.AddDays(xAxis.ActualInterval * i), yAxis.ActualMinimum + yInterval * i))
        //                 .ToList();

        var chart = GetParent<Chart>(this.AssociatedObject);

        //Style with hidden markers and some color
        var emptyDataPointStyle = new Style(typeof(DataPoint));
        emptyDataPointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataPoint.OpacityProperty, 0));
        emptyDataPointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataPoint.BackgroundProperty, this.LineColor));
        //Line series
        chart.Series.Insert(0, new LineSeries()
        {
            ItemsSource = lineSource,
            Title = "Middle Line",
            IndependentValuePath = "X",
            DependentValuePath = "Y",
            DataPointStyle = emptyDataPointStyle
        });
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    private T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject d) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (d == null)
            return null;

        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);
        if (parent != null && parent is T)
            return (T)parent;
        else return GetParent<T>(parent);
    }

    public class ChartPointModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public ChartPointModel(DateTime? x, double? y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        public DateTime? X { get; set; }

        public double? Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Advantage is only one: the line is real and has the same properties as DataSeries. But it requires much more code, has empty spaces on each side, closely connected to a type of a chart and doesn't change after the first appearance.

So try the first solution, and if it isn't what you expect - I will try to do something with the second solution.

Comment: Thanks very much, the first solution worked for me. Of course you deserve the bounty :)